# How to correctly include vue-router via cdn to make history mode working?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, scripting, cdn

I include scripts in html document like this:

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
```

In main.js when I write `mode: 'history'` nothing appears:

```
const routes = [
  {path: '/', name: 'blank', component: BlankPage},
  {path: '/directory1', name: 'directory1', component: Directory1},
  {path: '/directory2', name: 'directory2', component: Directory2},
  {path: '/directory3', name: 'directory3', component: Directory3},
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

When I remove `mode:'history'` web page appears. How to handle the situation?

Comment: mode: 'history' Is using to remove '#' from the URL.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see anything when I write this mode. Nothing is on the screen. Just white colored viewport.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet over here

Comment: Are you missing a `router-view`?

Comment: No, it's in html itself and it works unless mode history is established.

Comment: The `router-view` component is required for Vue Router to render anything. It might only appear to be "working", but it's not working as you configured. Can you link to a reproduction (e.g. in Codesandbox)?

Comment: I think https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-hill-1i5nl?file=/src/index.js this is working because files are on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

History mode requires some server, for example, a dev-server. So I've created a simple dev-server with the help of gulp.
gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  connect = require('gulp-connect');
 
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  connect.server({
    fallback: 'table.html'
  });
});
 
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('webserver'));
```

And now history mode works. If someone knows why it is that please tell me!